# Add function to EventListener & Keep arguments, Avoid Function Running Multiple Times

Tags: javascript, foreach, addeventlistener

I am stuck and I can't figure out how to fix my code.

This is my code:

```
    const updateScore = (isCorrect) => {
    // Update Game Variables
    if (isCorrect === true) {
      counter++
      score += 100;
    }
  }

  // Reset Styling
  const resetLoadedQuestionStyling = (isCorrect) => {
    questionScreen.style.display = 'none';
    answerArr.forEach(answer => {
      answer.classList.remove('correct');
      answer.classList.remove('wrong');
      answer.classList.remove('disable');

      updateScore(isCorrect)
    });
  }

  const styleAnswer = (div, isCorrect) => {
    if (isCorrect === true) {
      div.classList.add('correct');
    } else {
      div.classList.add('wrong');
      for (let i = 0; i < answerArr.length; i++) {
        if (i === currentQuestion.correct) {
          answerArr[i].classList.add('correct');
        }
      }
    }

    // Prevent Second Check
    answerArr.forEach(answer => {
      answer.classList.add('disable');
    });

    // Reset Styling
    setTimeout(() => {
      resetLoadedQuestionStyling(isCorrect);
    }, 3000);
  }

  const checkAnswer = (div, index) => {
    const userChoice = index;
    // Default Answer State
    let isCorrect = false;
    if (userChoice === currentQuestion.correct) {
      isCorrect = true;
    }
    styleAnswer(div, isCorrect);
  }

  answerArr.forEach((div, index) => {
    div.addEventListener('click', () => {
      checkAnswer(div, index);
    });
  });
```

I have an array, that consists of 4 divs. (`answerArr`).

I am comparing the index of the divs with my (`currentQuestion.correct`), which is stored in another array of objects.

Everything good so far. **The problem occurs, when I update my counter and my score.**

And I know exactly why:

```
answerArr.forEach((div, index) => {
    div.addEventListener('click', () => {
      checkAnswer(div, index);
    });
  });
```

This is running my `checkAnswer` function four times.. so my score gets increased four times, instead of one. (Example: counter = 4, score = 400 after one run.)

**An easy fix to this is to remove the function invoked in the event listener and place it directly in it.**

Example:

```
answerArr.forEach((div, index) => {
    div.addEventListener('click', checkAnswer);
  });
```

But than I can't pass my arguments (div and index) in order to properly move to the other functions.

Can you come up with a solution and help me.

Thank You all in advance!

Comment: Are you saying that clicking on an answer within a single div is running the `click` listener once for each div, rather than just once for the div that was clicked on?

Comment: @RGreenstreet Yes, clicking on one of my divs is running `checkAnswer` function 4 times..and that is why my `updateScore` gets updated 4 times, instead of just once.